# MAMP Not Updating localhost and saying 'It works'

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, osx-yosemite

For years I've used MAMP, but with the latest version of OS X Yosemite and MAMP, it seems like the two aren't getting along together. Whether MAMP is running or not, when going to http://localhost/ in my browser or just "localhost" a white page loads that says "It works!" rather than displaying a list of all the folders and files in my MAMP htdocs folder.

Using the default 8888 Apache Port in MAMP's settings I'm able to get to the localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English page. But I cannot ever get to a list of those files which is why I'm using MAMP.

I just want to be able to use MAMP to test websites I'm building.

Comment: Seems like Firefox keeps adding to the URL when I just type "localhost:8888" so that it keeps taking me to www.localhost.com:8888/

However, Chrome isn't adding the "http://", "www." and ".com" which lets me view MAMP's directory of files that I needed.

So I guess using Chrome is the quick fix, but not sure why Firefox is doing this.

Comment: www and .com do not apply in your case. localhost is pointing to your loopback interface (127.0.0.1) but www. is a domain prefix for web server and .com a TLD and apply only for FQDN. Well I'd suggest that you type  http:// localhost:8888 in Firefox (without space).

Comment: Thanks, Florian! That did the trick! :)

Comment: Sigh... back to not working... now neither Firefox or Chrome works when I use "http:// www.localhost:8888/" (without the space) in the URL.

Firefox says "Problem loading page: Server not found"
Chrome says "403 Forbidden" and "I don't have permission to access / on this server."

Comment: you shouldn't use www... http:// localhost:8888

Comment: When I enter http:// localhost:8888 (without the space) in both Firefox and Chrome it takes me to www.localhost:8888 where it says "Forbidden" on Chrome and "Server not found" on Firefox. :(

Comment: Still have this issue... anybody have a fix? :(